# RegEx expression, String manipulations

Tags: java, regex

I have to following text format, i would like to extract content using template.

> Value{ABC,XYZ...}|Message{This is test message}

When i encounter above string i would like to extract contents of 'Value' and 'Message' without parsing entire string in Java.

Is it possible with Regular Expressions?

Comment: "Yes" is probably not the answer you are expecting :). Joking aside, is this the only form of the text format you can expect?

Comment: are value and message always followed by braces ??

Comment: I would recommend that you [parse it without RegEx if you can](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/10998/what-does-the-jamie-zawinskis-quotation-about-regular-expressions-mean). As Jamie Zawinski said: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible with a regular expression, assuming the format doesnt change.

http://rubular.com/r/R8WIonv6Oj <- follow this link for the example.

```
Value\{(.*)\}\|Message\{(.*)\}
```

Has two matching groups for what is in between the curly braces. You could, however, easily do this without resorting to regex

Answer (score 0):

If your string is always of the format you have mentioned, the below code works ...

```
String s = "Value{ABC,XYZ...}|Message{This is test message}";
System.out.println(s.split("value")[0].split("\\{")[1].split("}")[0]); //prints ABC,XYZ...
System.out.println(s.split("Message")[1].split("\\{")[1].split("}")[0]); //prints This is test message
```